# EC2 Name tag and its position

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have this code, it works but I soon realized standards is not something we do. In my code I am getting the Tags value for 'Name'. However, the way i do it, I am assuming it is the first tag at position 0. I am wrong to assume. How can I make it more robust to just look for value of the key 'Name' irrelevant of position?

```
 response = client.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name':'tag-key','Values':['Name']}]) 

for item in response['Reservations']:
    #pprint(item['Instances'])
        print("AWS Account ID: {}".format(item['OwnerId']))
        for instance_id in item['Instances']:
            #print(instance_id)
            Tags = instance_id['Tags'][0]['Value']
            State = instance_id['State']['Name']
            print("EC2 Name: {}".format(Tags))
            print("Instance Id is: {}\nInstance Type is: {}".format(instance_id['InstanceId'],instance_id['InstanceType']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to **iterate** over `Tags` and **search** for the tag with `Key` of `Name`:

```
for item in response['Reservations']:

        print("AWS Account ID: {}".format(item['OwnerId']))

        for instance_id in item['Instances']:

            Tags = instance_id['Tags']

            tag_name_value = ""

            for tag in Tags:
                if tag['Key'] == "Name":
                    tag_name_value = tag["Value"]
                    break

            State = instance_id['State']['Name']

            print("EC2 Name: {}".format(tag_name_value))
            print("Instance Id is: {}\nInstance Type is: {}".format(
                    instance_id['InstanceId'],instance_id['InstanceType']))
```

Comment: thank you for info. I do have one question. when I do this I receive a list  key/value pairs of all tags for the ec2 instance.  I think I may be doing something wrong

Comment: @Randal Have you also changed print: ` print("EC2 Name: {}".format(tag_name_value))`?

Comment: As I said, I must of did something wrong... I did... Thank you... worked perfect!!!

Answer (score 1):

For a more Pythonic version:

```py
response = ec2_client.describe_instances()

for reservation in response['Reservations']:
    for instance in reservation['Instances']:
        if name := [tag['Value'] for tag in instance['Tags'] if tag['Key'] == 'Name']:
            print(name[0])
```

Or using resource methods:

```py
ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

for instance in ec2_resource.instances.all():
    if name := [tag['Value'] for tag in instance.tags if tag['Key'] == 'Name']:
        print(name[0])
```

(Requires Python 3.8)

Comment: thanks for the alternatives. I think your examples are  list comprehension.  For some reason those confuse me. so I have been sticking to the long route of getting the answer.